# path not found when using '+' in HttpClient path in VssConnection (VSTS)

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, azure-devops-rest-api

I use the following procedure to get the QueryHierarchyItem of a path. This works fine as long as there is no '+' character in the path. If there is a + in the path I get an `VssServiceResponseException: Not Found` Error.

I tried to use `Uri.EscapeDataString`, but that does not change anything and tried to manually replace the + with "%2B" with same results.

```
var wCred = new WindowsCredential(System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials);
var cred = new VssCredentials(wCred);
var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("..."), cred);
var witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
var queryHierarchyItem = witClient.GetQueryAsync("...", "path/that has/a + sign", depth: 1).Result;
```

Do I have to replace or ecscape it differently or is this a bug?

Comment: You're correct that it should be %2b for a literal "+". If you manually replace perhaps its subsequently being double encoded somewhere else.

Comment: Do you have any idea what I can do or why it won't work with `Uri.EscapeDataString`? It does also transform the plus to %2B. It also replaces spaces to %20 and Slashes to %2F, what does work too, unless there is a '+'.

Comment: Looking at the [docs for this call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) it looks like the "+" character would have to go in the URI path rather than the query string; this may run into URI validation by the server (specifically [layer 2 here](https://blogs.iis.net/nazim/use-of-special-characters-like-in-an-iis-url) )...